# Rules: Copying field from user's account to field in content type

Tags: 7, rules

D7.
Using the File Field Rules module, I am trying to copy the content of the image field of the user's account ("picture") to another image field ("field_node_image") in the same user's image gallery (each user has his own photo gallery.)

The purpose of this is for when a user uploads a picture to his account profile, a copy of it is also posted in his image gallery along with all the other pictures he may post there (displayed via Views.)

The module requires the selection of a source entity and a destination entity. Then a field is chosen from each entity.

I am making the event react upon updating the user's account, so that gives me access to the "account" selector for the source entity where the module finds the "picture" field.

But I need help in finding the destination selector. This, evidently, should be a node since the gallery is a content type. It also has to be a node that belongs to the user. But all base selectors I have begin by "site" or "account."

Can anyone help me find this second selector?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add some more stuff in that Rule; namely, following from your explanation, you need to:

1. "Create a new entity": Create a new node in an action, before the image-copying action. This new entity is a Gallery-type node.
2. Use the "entity_created" variable as the destination entity.

That should be enough to accomplish your goal, hope this helped some!

**Appendix A**: An export of such a Rule that worked.

```
{ "rules_196457" : {
    "LABEL" : "196457",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "file_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "account:field-user-image:file" ] } },
      { "NOT data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "account:field-user-image:file" ],
          "value" : [ "account-unchanged:field-user-image:file" ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "article",
            "param_title" : "New pic for [account:name] | [site:current-date]",
            "param_author" : [ "account" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "new_article" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "file_rules_copy_file" : {
          "source_entity" : [ "account" ],
          "source_field" : "field_user_image",
          "destination_entity" : [ "new-article" ],
          "destination_field" : "field_image",
          "remove_source" : "0"
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "A new Article has been created with the new user\u0027s image" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Appendix B**: An screenshot of the Rules UI

[image]

Comment: Interesting logic, I wouldn't have figured it out by myself. When the action creates the entity, the picture in it does not show, just an empty placeholder. Is there something else I should add?

Comment: You need two actions, right? First creates the gallery node entity, second one copies the image from user into the new entity. Did you set it up like this?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I need to fix other rules issues before I tackle this one. Will revert soon. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Good to hear you are still on this. Looking forward to an update. Thanks for the ping!

Comment: I am about to give up on this thing. Creating a new entity works but doesn't name a field to have a photo inside. So I had to add an action "set data value" to the created entity field taking the field from the user's picture. That worked. But I still can't copy the content of the new field to the gallery (1) it appears the module doesn't work and (2) outside the module, I still can't find the right selector to copy the image field to. So it's back to square one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hold on... :-) I can give you a working example of a rule that does what you need. Did you add and extra field for the user's image? Or do you use the default one?

Comment: The File Field Rules module will only work with additional field attached to a user's profile, not with the default 'picture' one. Is that an option for you, to add an additional picture field and use that instead of the default 'picture' one?

Comment: Yes. A while ago, I added an image field (called "field_user_image") to the user's profile. It replaces the default picture field thanks to the User Picture Field module. That's what I work with.

Comment: Okey, here is an export of a working rule, that creates a new Article node when a user updates his profile.

Comment: Yes, I understand the logic but not concerning "destination_entity" :; ["new-article"]  Where do you get that from? It's got to be a content type. My selectors do not show content types as possible destination entities. I don't even have "node" as possible destination entity. I see the destination field however.

Comment: The [new-article] is created before the file copying, look at the  [{"entity_create" :  part. A new node is created there. I will add a screen shot of my rules UI. You could also import this rule and check it yourself. Screenshot coming up!

Comment: My Provide is: "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } } and my destination_entity is entity-created. Still no pic appears in the article content type.

Comment: Wait a minute... I changed the variable to new_article and, indeed I see the destination new-article selector. It doesn't work because somehow my article content type has "lost" its image field. Let me try with another content type.

Comment: Yes, it does work! Somehow, using the default "entity-created" entity as destination didn't work Changing that variable name made it show up in the destination selectors. Now I just have to figure out why two of them are created but I guess that's the subject of more research or a new question. Thank you for your input and your help, made my day! :)

Comment: Great to hear, didn't feel like letting this one be... :-) Enjoy!